# What default CSS is preventing me from fully overlapping two elements with relative positioning?

Tags: html, css, css-position

Why don't `#img1` and `#canvas1` fully overlap in the below code? I want them in exactly the same place. I'm layering images with JavaScript animation on canvas. Initial thoughts were that the padding or margin default settings were interfering somewhere. I've tried setting to zero for all elements - it doesn't work. I understand that `position:relative` positions an element relative to it's normal position. Clearly missing a default setting or something obvious.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .chapter {
      width: 90%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      max-width: 1000px;
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
    
    #img1 {
      border: 1px solid green;
      position: relative;
      left: 50px;
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
    }
    
    #canvas1 {
      border: 1px solid blue;
      position: relative;
      left: -50px;
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="template" id="T2">
    <div class="chapter" id="C2">
      <h1>Why can't I overlap the below elements?</h1>
      <img src="" id="img1" />
      <canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things to do:

1.) Don't leave a linebreak or space between the two elements in the HTML code (see below)

2.) Set the `left` setting for canvas to `-52px` - you have to consider the 2 x 1px border of the image.

```css
.chapter {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#img1 {
  border: 1px solid green;
  position: relative;
  left: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#canvas1 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: relative;
  left: -52px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="template" id="T2">
  <div class="chapter" id="C2">
    <h1>Why can't I overlap the below elements?</h1>
    <img src="" id="img1" /><canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ah of course. Completely forgot about my borders. thanks

Comment: @Johannes I tried to solve it, I have a doubt, the `img` tag also has borders right, that too similar to `canvas` element, so why should we increase the pixels for `canvas` alone?

Comment: @NarenMurali Because the image is 52px wide including the borders, so the canvas would normally (without the `left` parameter) start at 52px from the left, so it has to be moved 52px to the left to exactly cover the image.

Comment: @Johannes Thank you for your time, that clarifies my doubt, I guess position absolute would be another fix, but great Answer!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

A couple of remarks:

- use `box-sizing: border-box` for 'easier' sizing. With `border-box` the border width and padding are substracted from the elemenent istead of added on to it. An element with `width: 100px`, a `border-width` of `1px` and a `padding` of `10px` will be 100 + (2 * 1) + (2 * 10) = 122px wide without `box-sizing: border-box` but the element will be 100px wide even with the `border-width` and `padding` when the `box-sizing` is set to `border-box`. See here for a (better) more detailed explanation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing
- When trying to overlap element I find it easiest to keep the surrounding container element as empty as possible. Taking out the `h1` element makes overlapping a lot more manageable.
- Change the `position` of the `canvas` element to `absolute`. This way it no longer takes up place in the DOM and it is positioned in the upper left container of its positioning parent (in your example the `div.chapter` in my answer the `div.container`). This also helps when trying to have elements line up.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.chapter {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#img1 {
  border: 1px solid green;
  position: relative;
  left: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#canvas1 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="template" id="T2">
  <div class="chapter" id="C2">
    <h1>Why can't I overlap the below elements?</h1>
    <div class="container">
      <img src="" id="img1" />
      <canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
    </div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ha, thanks for this, very helpful - I don't think box-sizing existed when I last got stuck into CSS.

Comment: `box-sizing` is one of my favorite CSS properties, it makes (the) life (of a frontend developer) so much easier!

Answer (score 0):

```
#img1 {
border: 1px solid green;
position: relative;
left: 56px;
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
```

this worked...

Comment: Question is why? I can add pixels to align but want to know why I need to do that?

Answer (score 0):

There are certainly better ways to achieve the effect you're going for but to answer your question, I believe the spacing is being caused by the default font size on the parent element. Set the font size to 0px on the chapter div and you can see the elements now overlap each other.